# Oxford versus Cambridge - a geographical puzzle

Tags: english, word-problem, geography

What is a geographical similarity between Cambridge University and Oxford University related to their 'titles'?

Comment: Both have the "University" title... lol

Comment: Both have the name Oxford, except Cambridge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in Jason's answer, both *bridge* and *ford* have to do with rivers, in these cases the [Cam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Cam) and the [Isis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Isis) portion of the [Thames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_Thames).

Etymonline's *[Cambridge](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Cambridge)* entry says

> Old English *Grontabricc* (c.745) “Bridge on the River Granta” (a Celtic river name, of obscure origin). The change to *Cante-* and later *Cam-* was due to Norman influence. The river name *Cam* is a back-formation in this case, but *Cam* also was a legitimate Celtic river name, meaning “crooked.”

Etymonline's *[Oxford](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Oxford)* entry says

> university town in England, Middle English *Oxforde*, from Old English *Oxnaforda* (10c.) literally “where the oxen ford.” In reference to a type of shoe laced over the instep, it is attested from 1721 (*Oxford-cut shoes*). Related: *Oxfordian; Oxfordish; Oxfordist; Oxfordy*.

The Cambridge/Oxford river-crossing coincidence is fairly minor, but see ELU's [OxFORD and CamBRIDGE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/131650) for more discussion of it.

A slightly deeper coincidence is that between *Oxford* and *[Bosphorus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosphorus#Name)*:

> The Greek name Βόσπορος (*Bosporos*) was folk-etymologized as from βοὸς πόρος, i.e. “cattle strait” (or “Ox-ford”), from the genitive of *bous* βοῦς “ox, cattle” + poros πόρος “passage”, thus “cattle-passage”, or “cow passage” in reference to Io from Greek mythology who was transformed into a cow and condemned to wander the earth until she crossed the Bosporus where she met Prometheus.... [wikipedia]

A number of 3-university (Oxford, Cambridge, Bosphorus) boat races have been held in Istanbul (see [hurriyetdailynews.com](http://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/default.aspx?pageid=438&n=eighth-oxford-cambridge-bosphorus-university-boat-race-to-be-held-1998-08-28)) analogous to the famous [University Boat Race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boat_Race) held annually on the Thames.

Comment: The "cows cross the river here" town name is extremely popular. Vancouver is named after a name derived from Van Couverden - and Couverden is Dutch for "cow ford"

Comment: This is why the portmanteau term "Oxbridge" sounds OK. (I think someone wrote a work of fiction with a "Camford" university too.)

Answer (score 2):

A bridge goes over a river and you ford a river?